# LightDM - default user session does not seem to work

Tags: lightdm

I need to choose which default window manager is choosen by LightDM at startup. I have edited `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`:

```
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=i3
autologin-user=ibox
```

It does not seem to work, it still boot on LXDE. I removed the `.dmrc` file in my home directory.

Comment: have you tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`  ? which will prompt you to make it default.

Comment: @arzyfex I have already tried, did not work. But `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lighdt` does not prompt me anything.

Answer (score 0):

Run the command :

```
sudo nano ~/.xinitrc
```

Add the following line :

```
exec i3
```

Or:

```
exec /usr/bin/i3
```

then edit `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` :

```
nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

And add the following line :

```
user-session=i3
autologin-user-timeout=0
```

Reboot using `sudo init 6` .

Comment: Nope, still booting on LXDE...
Note : I use autologin in my `lightdm.conf`